# Scala / Gradle project ... where to store files required for unit testing that are super large ?

Tags: java, unit-testing, scala, gradle, bigdata

I'm using Scala along side gradle and ScalaTest.

Just wondering ... where do people store file objects that are "large" ( 65 MB ) but are required by the unit testing. My application does image processing on such large files.

I have a function that takes the local link of such a file and calculates a useful metric :-)

I would like to unit test this function. I would like to have about 10 unit tests for this function , so I'm looking at 10 distinct image files( 65 * 10 = 650MB ) ....Where should I store this data ? Any thoughts ? One idea is to store it on S3 and have it download automatically every time when the unit testing is initiated ? Storing the data in the source code repository would be bad since it would make downloading the source code such a longer process .. .Any thought ? What do you guys think ?

Cheers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either make the files accessible via some URL and download them from your tests (if they don't already exist locally), or package them up as Maven/Ivy dependencies, publish them to a Maven/Ivy repository, and pull them in using Gradle's dependency management. It's generally not a good idea to use version control for files that large.

Answer (score 0):

Well if your using Git.... I would use [Git Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-6.html) and if your not using git I would still use a separate git repository to host the large-but-no-really-that-large files.

Heres the thing. Those files are not that big by todays standards and as a developer if I can source control it... I source control it unless its:

- Never ever going to change and publicly available (ie released libraries).
- Massively large in the gigabytes

If you don't use git I suppose you could write something in the unit test to download the files but then you will probably want to do a checksum of the file for validation and if the files change wouldn't it be nice to only download the delta..... all of which **git** does.

Seriously though if you do want to go download the files automagically from your unit test have a look at [jgit](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/) but I would just include developer instructions and or build script to manually execute git to go download the files.